# Java: Reading from getResourceAsStream gets too many bytes

Tags: java, utf-8, classloader

I'm trying to read a binary file, using getResourceAsStream. The problem is I get too many bytes back. The file is 56374 bytes long, according to ls, but when I read it in my code, I consistently get 85194 bytes.

```
InputStream fileData = checkNotNull(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
byte [] b = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileData);
int count = b.length;
```

I get the same result with similar code:

```
InputStream fileData = checkNotNull(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
byte [] b = new byte[1000*1000];
int count  = fileData.read(b);
```

If I run the code without the resource, everything is fine, I get the correct number of bytes.

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    byte [] b = new byte[1000*1000];
    int count  = fis.read(b);
```

The first bytes of the data I read match. Checking the output, the first byte that doesn't match is "CO", which comes out as "ef bf bd".

Maybe somehow it's trying to convert to/from UTF-8? Everything should be binary here. There is no text involved.

Any help appreciated.

Edit: I'm pretty sure I'm reading the correct file. If I rename the file, the read fails. Change it back, it works. I changed the resource name in intellij, and it refactored and changed the name in the code, which still worked.

Edit2: I was wrong. I'm not looking at the correct file. I traced into getResourceAsStream. Our build system copies the file to a build output directory, and runs from there.. This destination file is the wrong size, so it appears the copy is doing some damage.

Note that it would copy the file again, any time I changed the name, which is why I thought I had the right file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you are actually reading a different version of the file when you read it as a resource.  The JVM reads resources as located by the classloader.  So when you resolve the same `path` string as a resource and as a file, there is a good chance they are resolving to different things.

I doubt that the root issue is Unicode or UTF-8.  Your examples show that you are reading the state using `InputStream`.  That approach is encoding agnostic ... and will give you the raw bytes from the file(s).  A regular `InputStream` doesn't *try* to decode the bytes it reads.

Having said that, it is definitely significant that the bytes you are reading are different.  But that is *also* consistent with simply reading different files.

Comment: I have no justification for the unicode hypothesis. It should not be involved. "CO" should convert to "c3 80" in utf-8, not "ef bf bd". I was just trying to think of what expands to more characters when it sees a high bit set.

Comment: Also, I edited the question to clarify I'm sure I have the right file.

Comment: Well ... if your code is **really** reading the same file and repeatably getting different results, then possibly this due to some kind of classloader craziness; i.e. you are using a custom classloader that is mangling the data as you read the resource stream.   Either way, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Nope. You were right. See edit2 in question.